# Files.write(Paths.get(), lines, utf8) - java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, file-io, access-denied

I am trying the write a short line (approx. 150 characters) to a file using the following code on the server side:

```
public void printToFile(String filePath, List<String> printLine) {

    Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("1st line", "2nd line");

    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("file5-test.txt"), lines, utf8);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Done
}
```

Note: this is a test and I will replace the relevant fields with the input fields filePath and printLine when I get this working.

I found another similar issue where the coder had an incorrect path being passed. I do not think that applies to my code as I have, temporarily, hard coded the file. I have seen many examples recommending this coding.

I get the following error in the log:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: file5-test.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3348)
    at org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection.printToFile(MySQLConnection.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is your java process allowed to write to the current working directory?

Comment: By the look of it, you don't have write access to the directory the file is in.

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis and @MintyFresh, Thanks for your help. How do I give permission for the application to write to C:\? Also, how do I ensure that the application has permission to write to the directory for all users that run this application? Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 0):

```
Files.write(Paths.get("file5-test.txt"), lines, utf8);
```

Paths.get("file5-test.txt") is not an absolute path. Make sure you use the absolute path.

Also please check whether file exist or not and if file exist then you should check whether file have write permission or not by using File.canWrite().

Comment: Hi @Swathi, Thanks for your help. I changed the file to "C:\\file5-test.txt" and I get the same error with the new file path (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\file5-test.txt). The file does not currently exist and I plan to prevent this from occurring by appending a time stamp to the file name. Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can not, under Windows 8.1, create a file in the c:\ directory. If I change this to C:\Users\Glyndwr\Documents then it works. So I need to accept a destination folder from the user (I do not think this can be done; it has to be a destination file) and check that it is not in c:\.

Regards,

Glyn